How to integrate the faceio api in nextjs app
Give the details about how we can integrate the faceio api in nextjs app for the face recognition and face comparing
I was trying to build an ai face recognition attendance system.
But I don't know how integrate faceio api in the nextjs app

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
